# Using a USB wireless adapter to secretly share wifi: would anyone know?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point

there's no wifi in our office so I'm planning to use a usb wifi adapter to share my computer's internet to my phone. However, I'm afraid our company's IT department might know. Would they? I mean, is there any way for them to tell that I'm making my own wireless connection from my computer?

Many usb adapters look like flash drives so I'm planning to get those to disguise it as flash drive. Also, many people in our office use their phone as wifi hotspot so I'm thinking maybe my setup could be mistaken as phone tethering wifi.

Don't ask me why there's no wifi here. Pretty sure it's for "productivity" purposes. It sucks, I know. So I want to do a workaround.

Thanks.

Comment: By doing this and bypassing the companies proxy/firewall/internet restrictions you may well be breaking IT policy and could be fired.

Comment: My understanding is that the traffic from the phone will go through the same proxy/firewall/whatever as the regular traffic, and connections to e.g. `m.facebook.com` may as well be authorized. Creating a wireless segment with unrestricted access to corporate resources sounds like more of an issue.

Comment: Questions about things that could be at odds with, or should be coordinated with, your company's IT department are off-topic on Super User.

Comment: Fair comment. However, the OP does not ask how to bypass IT policies or whether his actions are conform to policies. The answer I give doesn't promote such actions and only gives technical details about how such actions can be detected. The only issue I see is that the asker confesses his plans here. Maybe it's possible to edit the question so it can stay?

Comment: The answer to the question "would anyone know" is "yes, if someone is checking then they would be able to know."

Answer (score 2):

Sharing WIFI via a wireless adapter will look different from a WIFI hotspot created by a smartphone (peer-to-peer vs infrastructure connections). Also, your phone will certainly connect to mobile versions of websites, which can be noticed if your IT department does traffic analysis.